# ActivePrinter not works for embedded documents

Tags: vba, excel, printing

My default printer in `Control Panel> Printer and Faxes`, is **`HP LaserJet P2035 on Ne02:`**

I have **two** active printers connected to my system.

I want `PrintOut` with my second printer which is: **`HP LaserJet Pro MFP M127-M128 PCLmS on Ne01:`**

There is a *MS-Word document which embedded* (**as an Icon**) in `Sheet1`

I `PrintOut` above embedded document.

My code is:

```
Sub PrintJob()

    Dim ObjWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document

    'Initialization
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("WDoc").Activate
    Set ObjWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    ObjWord.Visible = False
    Set objDoc = ObjWord.activedocument
    Application.ActivePrinter = "HP LaserJet Pro MFP M127-M128 PCLmS on Ne01:"

    objDoc.PrintOut

End Sub
```

Unfortunately the `PrintOut` done with `HP LaserJet P2035 on Ne02:` printer.

So the `PrintOut` does not accept the `ActivePrinter` argument.

The point is the `PrintOut` with changing `ActivePrinter` is act rightly when using in `Worksheet` Print. (as below)

```
Application.ActivePrinter="HP LaserJet Pro MFP M127-M128 PCLmS on Ne01:"
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Printout
```

But the problem is for changing `ActivePrinter` and `objDoc.PrintOut` (first above code), is the `ActivePrinter` is not effective and `PrintOut` have done with my **System Default Printer**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case (*set specific printer for printing an embedded document*), the point is that we should set printer for the embedded object `Application` object.

Sub PrintJob()

```
    Dim ObjWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document

    'Initialization
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("WDoc").Activate
    Set ObjWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    ObjWord.Visible = False
    Set objDoc = ObjWord.activedocument

    'Here we set the ActivePrinter for the objWord's Application object:
    objWord.Application.ActivePrinter = "HP LaserJet Pro MFP M127-M128 PCLmS on Ne01:"

    objDoc.PrintOut

End Sub
```